# Hint on solving a problem in Euclidean geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

How do i prove the following problem:

If a quadrilateral has sides of length $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, prove
that its area $S$ satisfies the following inequality
$$4S\leq (a+c)(b+d)$$
with equality holding only for rectangles.

Hint: Twice the area of a triangle is $a b \sin \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the sides of lengths $a$, $b$. But how do i use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The triangle with sides $a$ and $b$ has the area
$$A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin \alpha\leq\frac{1}{2}ab$$
with the expressions equal if and only if $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Do the same for each pair of sides and label these areas $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$ and note that
$$
2S=A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4$$
and
$$ab+ad+cb+cd = (a+c)(b+d)$$

Comment: $S\leq ab$ is not generally true for all quadrilateral

Comment: Right, I just noticed. I'll change it to account for that.

Comment: aren't you suppose to prove 4S≤(a+e)(b+d)?

Comment: He's asking for a hint so I've outlined the general method to prove what he wants. If you can't see the next step, it's to double $2S$ to get the desired inequality.

Comment: $2S\leq \frac{1}{2}(ad+ bc+ ab+ cd)$, then $4S\leq (a+c)(b+d)$

Comment: I'll change the side $e$ to side $c$ for clarity in both my answer and the question.

Comment: how can i prove that if a triangle has sides of lengths a, b, c, then its area
S satisfies the inequality$$4S\sqrt{3} \leq a^{2} + b^{2 }+c^{2}$$ with equality holding only for equilateral triangles.